# Controlling an SSL Website with Python

Tags: javascript, python, ssl, web, controls

I'm trying to automate the process of getting my current student records at my college. In a browser the process involves typing in my college's URL, then clicking on the login link which then brings me to a https:// URLed page were I type my password and user-name in. Then from there it is one or two more links and reading some text on the page. Now, my question is, how might I go about do doing this but in an automated way, so my records would be displayed on the command line. The https:// in the URL signifies, I think, that it uses SSL are there certain libraries that can handle this? Also the 'submit' button on the login page I'm pretty sure uses JavaScript, again, are there libraries to handle this?

I'm sure I missed something or other in my question's description, so please ask if you do not understand my question or need more information.

PS. I am not well versed in Internet protocols and I am also new to Python. In fact I started studying it for this project. But, I am fluent in C and I am pretty good with C++.

Thanks in advance.
Michael,

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to mimic all the actions you do in the browser.

First.  There is no problem with https/ssl as long as you don't have to verify them (it seems that you don't have to), [`urllib2.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen) will handle them.

Second.  When you click 'Submit' browser sends a request to the server with your username, password and probably some other data.  The type of that request is probably POST.  As a response server will probably send you a cookie with session id.  So all you need to do is to investigate the exact format of request to the server (e.g. using FireBug), and get the cookie from the server's response.

Third.  Just use that cookie to navigate the pages on the site.  [This](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/articles/cookielib.shtml) might help.

P.S. As you see, there is too much 'probably' word in the answer - the exact authentication process may differ from described above and you'd have to investigate it by yourself.

Comment: You should avoid `urllib2` for HTTPS since it doesn't verify the certificate (see red box in linked documentation), which makes the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks. (Same applies to `httpclient`, unless you add the code to verify the cert yourself.) Something like pycurl would be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Roman's answer is good advice: you generally don't need to act like a real user when your script can call HTTP methods directly.

However, if you are not comfortable with reverse engineering the HTTP operations that the site requires, then an alternative would be to use [Selenium](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium), a tool for simulating interaction with web pages.  Selenium is usually used by web application developers to test their applications, but it can also be used as an automatable client for an existing website.